# var in g:each returning toString() not object

Tags: grails, each, var, gsp

I have a list of objects (area.ipgr.riesgos) in which I pretend to take each element and access the attribute "nombre" in each one of them. However, in this implementation, when I try to use the variable ${riesgo.nombre} of the g:each, I get the error "Can not get property 'nombre' on null object".

It is worth mentioning that when I print "risk" separately as a test I get the toString() associated with the domain, even using getClass() I notice that it is an object of the correct type; but when trying to access an attribute of it, it appears as null.

Here's the code in the gsp:

```
<g:if test="${area.ipgr.riesgos}">
    <g:each var="riesgo" in="${area.ipgr.riesgos}" status="k" >
        <tr class="completo">
            <td><span id="rowNumber" class="rowNumber">${k + 1}</span></td>
            <td><textarea class="form-control popbox" data="nombre" 
            name="secciones[${i}].areas[${j}].ipgr.riesgos[${k}].nombre" 
            rows="1" onkeyup="checkComplete(this)">${riesgo.nombre}
            </textarea></td>

        </tr>           
    </g:each>
</g:if>
```

Comment: Probably some riesgos instances has nombre property set to null, try adding an elvis operator to avoid null exception. Like this `${riesgo?.nombre}`

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that already... And yes, with that consideration I can visualize the data that I am trying to recover ... But when I try to save (or edit and then save) it is as if those fields were still null.

Comment: Maybe if you could share a more complete scenario of what you are trying

Comment: try removing this name="secciones[${i}].areas[${j}].ipgr.riesgos[${k}].nombre" (I feel you can refactor this better)and change to ${riesgo?.nombre} to see if the page loads